# Why is this cane growing slow, and having yellow leaves?

Tags: houseplants

My Dieffenbachia plant is not doing too well right now.
[image: Dumb Cane]

All the other leaves yellowed up and fell off. These remaining ones are barely moving (as in, not opening up quickly).

I have a suspicion that it might be over fertilization. I think I will put it under running water for a bit of time, in order to remove excess fertilizer.

There were some aphids before, but I cleaned those out, and haven't seen any in a while.

Any other suggestion/advise?

Comment: What makes you think it could be over fertilization? It certainly could be but I am just curious.

Comment: Is the plant normally indoors with no exposure to sunlight?

Comment: @Rob, I've topped up the top soil with compost. That was a while ago, but I think it is the only variable that've changed.

Comment: @TimNevins, yes, the plant is almost always indoors (in the office). it gets a semi decent exposure to sunlight as it is close to the window, but it is facing a north side.

Comment: @Roman Assuming it has been growing steady, in it's current environment, for awhile now; then I would just go with your gut.